# How to add into an array 2 variables that are also arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the below code:

Here I declare the code for getting the category name and slug

```
    $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => 0,
        'taxonomy'           => 'category'
        );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        $categories_name = array(); // here i get the category name
    $categories_ids = array(); // here i get the category slug
    foreach($categories as $category){
          $categories_name[] = $category->name;
      $categories_ids[] = $category->slug;
        }
```

Here is the setting that is echoed in my back-end with the category name for the user to select

```
    $this->settings['categoriesmain3'] = array(
          'section' => 'general',
          'title'   => __( 'Select Right Block Category' ),
          'desc'    => __( 'Here you can select the main category for main right block.' ),
          'type'    => 'select',
          'std'     => '',
          'choices' =>  array('$categories_name' => '$categories_ids') //I am trying to do 
        );
    $settings = get_option('mytheme_options');
    $my_choices_cat3  = $settings['categoriesmain3'];
```

I am trying to add in `choices =>` the code `array('$categories_name' => '$categories_ids')'` but it doesn't work like that. In my example for manually adding the select field I have `'choices' =>  array('Choice 1' => 'choice1', 'Choice 2' => 'Choice 2')`, so what is the correct syntax for the `choices` element where i want to add a dynamic list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by creating one array, using the category names as keys and the category ids as values.

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
$categories_options = array();

foreach($categories as $category){
  $categories_options[$category->name] = $category->slug;
}
```

You can then use the following line to add the list.

```
'choices' => $categories_options
```